# Using Numpy to load in Large data files?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am attempting to load in a large array as part of a small project I'm working on from a .dat.

I usually use numpy.loadtxt to read in data from my files to form single column arrays where if my file was:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Where I use:

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt("123.dat", Unpack =True)
```

To assign the 3 columns to arrays 1,2 and 3. The file I'm working with has the following format.

```
0000000000 4.975124E-03 -3.046211E+00 -1.148806E+00
0000000001 2.543665E-06 -3.661235E+00 -1.038111E+00
0000000002 2.543665E-06 -1.285855E+01 1.251881E+00
```

This format repeats for about 52k lines in my file.
Yet when I try to use the same method and try using the following.

```
i, m, x, y = np.loadtxt("stars.dat", unpack=True)
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    i, m, x, y = np.loadtxt("stars.dat")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

I've tried altering the arguments to usecols = (1,2...) however this doesn't collect the values correctly into the matrices, it selects random values from my file which aren't aligned in the columns.

How do I go about solving this error and what is the correct way in using Numpy to import large sets of data from a file and assign them to arrays in future?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample should unpack into 4 variables as expected.  There must be something different about that file.  The error indicates that it is finding more than 4 columns.  The problem with `usecols` further indicates that your concept of columns in the file differs from what `loadtxt` sees.  It could be a problem with the delimiter.

With your sample:

```
In [114]: txt=b"""0000000000 4.975124E-03 -3.046211E+00 -1.148806E+00
     ...: 0000000001 2.543665E-06 -3.661235E+00 -1.038111E+00
     ...: 0000000002 2.543665E-06 -1.285855E+01 1.251881E+00"""

In [119]: data=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines())
In [120]: data.shape
Out[120]: (3, 4)
In [121]: data.dtype
Out[121]: dtype('float64')
```

the plain load finds 3 rows, 4 columns.  It's a good idea to do a simple load like this to make sure you are reading the file correctly.

`unpack` just transposes the array:

```
In [122]: data=np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), unpack=True)
In [123]: data.shape
Out[123]: (4, 3)
In [124]: i,j,k,l=data
```

which can then be unpacked afterwards.  Unpacking is the the normal Python assignment to a tuple of variables.  Apart from the transpose `loadtxt` doesn't do anything special with `unpack`.